# Advanced filter not working VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run an advanced filter, but when I run it, my data gets hidden..Do you know why?

```
Sub AdvancedFilter()
'
' AdvancedFilter Macro


 Range("E34").Select
    Range("E34:P" & Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Rules").Range("B3:M4"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

So, attached my rules(which is same header) and where I want my data goes.

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to have any criteria specified in your "rules".  Is that intentional?

Comment: My Criteria is Range B3:M4 of the Sheet Rules. but I made a chance and now seems to be working. Thanks anyway

Comment: I just meant that (assuming your "rules" are the top part of the image) the criteria, i.e. cells B4:M4, were completely blank, which would mean you wouldn't be filtering on anything.  As long as it's working now though, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `"Action:=xlFilterInPlace"` to `"Action:=xlFilterCopy"` to copy the data to another worksheet. Because your method filters it in place, hides data and data only filtered by criteria is shown.